# Probability. Why **TH** and **HT**, but only **HH**

Tags: probability

Why is there only one probability of **HH** (tossing a coin) but $2$ for **HT** and **TH**. We use combinatorics to find no.of combinations. That is $^2C_1 \times {}^2C_1$. But combination says that **TH** and **HT** are the same. Why do we take **HT** and **TH** to be different but **HH** and **HH** to be same.

Comment: What do you mean by "one probability" and "2 probability"?

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the problem of flipping two fair coins in sequence, there are indeed many different sample spaces we could use to describe it.  The benefit to using the sample space $\{HT,TH,HH,TT\}$ over $\{2H,1H1T,2T\}$ is that in the first, each outcome is equally likely to occur, unlike in the second.  That does not make the second an incorrect choice for the sample space, merely an *inconvenient* one.

Comment: In a related question, consider when you play the lottery.  You have two outcomes, you either win or you lose.  So, you could consider the sample space $\{win,lose\}$.  This however does not imply that you win half of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Let mark 1st coin as A and 2nd coin as B now there is H on A and T on B is one case while H on B and T on A is another case. On other hand H on A and H on B is same as H on B and H on A.

Answer (score 1):

While tossing a coin we consider the events of both coins simultaneously. However in case of TH, the T represents first coin and H second one. Hence in case of HH it doesn't matter as both coin will have H on them